# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database (Only when unit testing the app)

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing

So I have recently added persistence in my application and I get this error, the interesting part though is that the application runs fine even persists objects retrieves them and everything but when running unit test I get the error written above.

Here are the interesting parts of my app

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission." />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Here is the gradle config defailtConfig block

```
 compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mehungry.com.myapplicationnavigationdawerdemo"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
```

My DatabaseHelper :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MeHungryApp.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.ATABLE);
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.BTABLE);
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.CTABLE);

        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.DTABLE);
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.ETABLE);
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.FTABLE);
        db.execSQL(CreateStatments.GTABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ATableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BTableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CTableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DTableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ETableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTableDef.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GTableDef.TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

My database Test class(doing nothing for now)

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MealEntityPersistenceTest {

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

public MealEntityPersistenceTest() {

}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    databaseHelper = new 
DatabaseHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext());
    database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


@Test
public void testInsertRecipe() {
}


}
```

And here is what I ger in the Android Monitor

```
    05-18 18:16:12.437 12672-12672/? I/MonitoringInstrumentation: Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 0
05-18 18:16:12.438 12672-12695/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
05-18 18:16:12.439 12672-12695/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30046: (2) open(/data/data/mehungry.com.myapplicationnavigationdawerdemo.test/databases/MeHungryApp.db) - 
05-18 18:16:12.441 12672-12695/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/mehungry.com.myapplicationnavigationdawerdemo.test/databases/MeHungryApp.db'.
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:202)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1181)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
   at mehungry.MealEntityPersistenceTest.setUp(MealEntityPersistenceTest.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
   at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
05-18 18:16:12.442 12672-12695/? I/TestRunner: failed: testInsertRecipe(mehungry.MealEntityPersistenceTest)
05-18 18:16:12.442 12672-12695/? I/TestRunner: ----- begin exception -----
05-18 18:16:12.443 12672-12695/? I/TestRunner: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:218)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:202)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1181)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
   at mehungry.MealEntityPersistenceTest.setUp(MealEntityPersistenceTest.java:37)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
   at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
05-18 18:16:12.443 12672-12695/? I/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

I am getting desperate since I have seen tons of similar issues but nothing helped me, so any kind of direction or wild guess will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So after some investigation I figured out that the problem lies in the database path

when in test :

```
/data/data/mehungry.com.myapplicationnavigationdawerdemo.test/databases/MeHungryApp.db
```

when running whole application:

```
/data/data/mehungry.com.myapplicationnavigationdawerdemo/databases/MeHungryApp.db
```

This was the problem, this inconsistency was fixed for me 
when I did change my DatabaseHelper constructor invocation

from this :

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext());
```

to this :

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
```

Hope it might help somebody at somepoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! From documentation and samples online, it does seems like getContext() is the one, but getTargetContext() solved it for me as well.

Comment: Thanks! This issue took me a few hours of SO... Somebody should update the Google documentation with this information.

Comment: thanks for this answer, now the question/answer has risen in google results too i guess, very useful, sharp!